# How to get only time from 1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime, time

I want to get only time from 1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z. Like 9.30 or 16:00. How to do this?

Comment: `'1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z'.split('T')[1].split(':').slice(0,2).join(':')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `Date` class. Here a short Example:

```js
const d = new Date('1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z') // Parses a ISO 8601 Date
console.log(d.getHours()); // gets the hours in the timezone of the browser.
console.log(d.getUTCHours()); // gets the hours in UTC timezone.
console.log(d.getMinutes()); // gets the minutes in the timezone of the browser.
console.log(d.getUTCMinutes()); // gets the minutes in UTC timezone.
console.log(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes());
console.log(d.getUTCHours() + ':' + d.getUTCMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Date pipe in Angular like below:

```
{{ 2019-06-26T19:31:00.000Z | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}}
```

It will give following output:

**27/06/2019 01:01:00**

For only time use the following:

```
{{ 2019-06-26T19:31:00.000Z | date:"HH:mm"}}
```

It will give following output:

**01:01**

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
date = new Date('1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z');

// and after this target by:
date.getFullYear()
date.getMonth()
date.getDate();
```

and other needed params.

Answer (score -1):

[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is a great time management library for JS projects, [Check it out !](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: add link in commet

Answer (score -1):

you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) like this:

```
 let YourDate = '1970-01-01T09:30:00.000Z'
 let time= moment(YourDate).format("hh:mm a")
```

Following is a stackbliz url that will help:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-momentjs-format-datetime-5etqib?file=app/app.component.ts